# After deploying, the app fails to upload files to S3 gives Unexpected token < error

Tags: meteor, meteor-slingshot

I tried to upload files to my S3 bucket bay getting the credentials from the Ec 2 instance (The app is hosted in EC2). Here's the directive :

```
var credentials = new AWS.EC2MetadataCredentials();

var updateCredentials = Meteor.wrapAsync(credentials.get, credentials);


Slingshot.createDirective("achievementPhotoUpload", Slingshot.S3Storage.TempCredentials, {
  bucket: "...",

  acl: "public-read",

  region: "...",

  temporaryCredentials: function () {
    if (credentials.needsRefresh()) {
      updateCredentials();
    }

    return {
      AccessKeyId: credentials.accessKeyId,
      SecretAccessKey: credentials.secretAccessKey,
      SessionToken: credentials.sessionToken
    };
  },

  authorize: function () {
    //Deny uploads if user is not logged in.
    if (!this.userId) {
      var message = "Please login before posting files";
      throw new Meteor.Error("Login Required", message);
    }

    return true;
  },

  key: function (file) {
    return "achievement-photos/" + file.name;
  }
});
```

But it won't upload. When I check the logs, I found this :

```
Session terminated, terminating shell... ...terminated.
`Meteor.addCollectionExtension` is deprecated, please use `CollectionExtensions.addExtension`
Exception while invoking method 'slingshot/uploadRequest' SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.Future.wait (/opt/kwabackend/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:420:15)
    at packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1
    at Object.temporaryCredentials (server/uploaders/AchievementPhotosAccess.js:21:7)
    at Object.Slingshot.S3Storage.TempCredentials._.defaults.applySignature (packages/edgee_slingshot/packages/edgee_slingshot.js:776:$
    at Object.Slingshot.S3Storage.upload (packages/edgee_slingshot/packages/edgee_slingshot.js:696:1)
    at [object Object]._.extend.getInstructions (packages/edgee_slingshot/packages/edgee_slingshot.js:343:1)
    at [object Object].Meteor.methods.slingshot/uploadRequest (packages/edgee_slingshot/packages/edgee_slingshot.js:425:1)
    at packages/check/match.js:103:1
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
    at Object.Match._failIfArgumentsAreNotAllChecked (packages/check/match.js:102:1)
    - - - - -
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /opt/kwabackend/app/programs/server/npm/peerlibrary_aws-sdk/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/metadata_service.js:115:38
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/opt/kwabackend/app/programs/server/npm/peerlibrary_aws-sdk/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/metadata_serv$
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:492:13)
```

Any idea what's happening?

Line 21 of `AchievementPhotosAccess.js` :

```
updateCredentials();
```

Comment: Can you show us these two lines of code:

at packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1
    at Object.temporaryCredentials (server/uploaders/AchievementPhotosAccess.js:21:7)

Comment: @StephenWoods Hi, I don't know how to locate the helpers.js but Line 21 of `AchievementPhotosAccess.js` is `updateCredentials();`

Comment: What's in `credentials.get`?

Comment: @StephenWoods Looks like a method in `EC2MetadataCredentials`  a method in AWS sdk.

Comment: Is it possibly that the bucket policy in AWS is not correct?

Comment: @PhilipPryde I added the right CORS and it did upload a file in development (But in development I gave the access key and secret. In production it take the credentials from the EC2 instance). Might that be the issue? Also the bucket and the instance are in two different regions. Might that be an issue?

Comment: @PhilipPryde I just created another bucket in the same region... But still the same issue.